# Anyone know how to use ACF and show custom fields for logged in users only on a post?

Tags: custom-field

Anyone know how to use ACF and show custom fields for logged in users only on a post?

Update: I think conditional formatting is what im after?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: On the front end or the back end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the template you just need to check if the current user's logged in with [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). Then output whatever HTML/PHP (including ACF functions) that you only want to show logged in users:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
    <!-- Output for only logged in users here. -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Exactly what i wanted!

- How would i say "please login to view content" if they are not logged in?

Comment: Use an `else:`.

Comment: <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
else: { echo "please log in"
<?php endif; ?>

doesn't seem to work

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp